# How to make Powershell pass a list as argument to gcloud

Tags: powershell, neural-network, gcloud

I want to submit my neural network model to google cloud via the following command as in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/train-ml-model-pytorch#gpu_1):

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training ${JOB_NAME} \
  --region=us-central1 \
  --master-image-uri=gcr.io/cloud-ml-public/training/pytorch-gpu.1-10 \
  --scale-tier=CUSTOM \
  --master-machine-type=n1-standard-8 \
  --master-accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1 \
  --job-dir=${JOB_DIR} \
  --package-path=./trainer \
  --module-name=trainer.task \
  -- \
  --train-files=gs://cloud-samples-data/ai-platform/chicago_taxi/training/small/taxi_trips_train.csv \
  --eval-files=gs://cloud-samples-data/ai-platform/chicago_taxi/training/small/taxi_trips_eval.csv \
  --num-epochs=10 \
  --batch-size=100 \
  --learning-rate=0.001
```

I was working with powershell and I have a problem with the master-accelerator argument which should be a dictionnary. I don't know how to pass such to gcloud. I have tried @{count=1; type=...}, but received a `Bad syntax for dict arg: [@]` error.

How can I pass a list of parameters in PowerShell such that the gcloud submit command accepts it?

I thank you in advance for your help.

---

**EDIT**

I have tried to use delimiters as ^^^^:^^^^, along [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping), but this still does not work (Invalid delimeter).

Comment: So, you're running this from within PowerShell? I would use the *stop parsing* operator if you don't want to quote the arguments: `gcloud --% ...`

Comment: This works in echoargs:  `echoargs --master-accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1`  Backslash doesn't continue lines in powershell.